# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'children') error java script cannot be solved

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, tree

I am doing a js tree with my js class I bind my child and parent ids and descriptions to the tree but I took this error. I have a list with name birimList it has my nodes ids paranet Id's and node names. I checked the list there is not a null referans.
this is my controller code and view code's java script.

```
public ActionResult GetTreeData()
    {
        var birimList = _ouListesiService.FindParentOUs();

  
        var nodes = birimList.Select(t => new JsTreeModel
        {
            id = t.Id.ToString(),
            parent = String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.ParentId.ToString()) ? "#" : t.ParentId.ToString(),
            text = String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.ChildDescription) ? "#" : t.ChildDescription,
            disabled = false,
            icon = "font-yellow-crusta" + "fa fa-folder"
        });

        return Json(nodes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            BindTree();

            $("#btnAra").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
               
                //$("#birimTree").jstree("search", val);
            });
        });

        function BindTree() {

            $.jstree.defaults.core.themes.variant = "large";
            $.jstree.defaults.core.multiple = false;
            $.jstree.defaults.core.dblclick_toggle = true;
            $.jstree.defaults.search.case_sensitive = false;
            $.jstree.defaults.search.show_only_matches = true;
            $.jstree.defaults.search.show_only_matches_children = true;

            $("#birimTree").jstree({
                "plugins": ["state", "dnd", "contextmenu", "changed", "search"],
                "search": {
                    "search_callback": function (searchString, node) {
                        if (node.text.toLocaleLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLocaleLowerCase()))
                            return true;

                        return false;
                    }
                },
                "core": {
                    "strings": { "Loading ...": "Birim Hiyerarşisi yükleniyor. Lütfen bekleyiniz ..." },
            
                    "themes": {
                        "name": "proton",
                        "responsive": true
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "type": "POST",
                        'data': $("#frmAraTree").serializeObject(),
                        "url": "@Url.EncryptAction("GetTreeData", "Kullanicilar")"
                    }
                },
                "contextmenu": {
                    "items": function (node) {
                        return {
                            "Detail": {
                                "label": "Detay",
                                "title": "Birime ait detay bilgileri görmek için tıklayın",
                                "icon": "font-purple-intense fa fa-info",
                                "action": function () {
                                    var birimId = node.id;
                                    var btnDetay = $("#btnBirimYeniDetay");

                                    if (!btnDetay.attr("href").contains("id")) {
                                        btnDetay.data("orjinalURL", btnDetay.attr("href"));
                                        btnDetay.attr("href", btnDetay.attr("href") + "?id=" + birimId);
                                    } else
                                        btnDetay.attr("href", btnDetay.data("orjinalURL") + "?id=" + birimId);

                                    btnDetay.trigger("click");
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }


    </script>
```

Comment: Your code does not have a `children` reference anywhere. If you get an error about `children`, then that error occurs on a line in other code, not this code.